# How to set header in request crossirigin.me? ERROR: Origin: header is required

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cors

I attempt to send a request for my app in meteor js and when i send it, the browser shows me the below message: **Origin: header is required**

This happend when i send this: http://crossorigin.me/https://scholar.google.cl/citations?user=n1qKMYwAAAAJ&hl=es

I'm using the CORS proxy http://crossorigin.me/

How to set this origin header and where?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,token');
//res.setHeader('*');
// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});
```